# Select2 return a placeholder value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, placeholder

I am looking to return a value from a select2 box when the placeholder is shown.  No matter what I do It returns null or empty instead of the expected value.  I want to somehow get '99999' in this example when the user has not chosen anything:

```
<select id='filter'>
<option value='1'>one</option>
<option value='2'>two</option>
<option value='3'>three</option>
</select>

...

$('#filter').select2 ({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: {
        id: '99999',
        text: 'select something'
    }
});

...

console.log($('#filter').val());  // returns null when placeholder visible
console.log($('#filter').select2('data'));  // returns [] when placeholder visible
```

Comment: If you want it to be treated like a normal value, make it one of the options instead of a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  The heart of the issue is the blank option requirement...but you need to include the id in the blank option.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select style="width:400px;" id="filter" >
  <option value="99999"></option>
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="2">example 2</option>
  <option value="3">example 3</option>
</select>
<button id="clickme">clickme</button>

$('#filter').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: {
        id: "99999",
        text: "select something"
    }
    //placeholder: "select something"
})
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    console.log($('#filter').children("option:selected").val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juwmb3oh/